# Word request: The best at what you do

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single-word adjective that means either "the best at what you do" or "the most experienced at what you do."  If forced to pick one of those two perspectives, I would choose the former.  I will be using it in the following list:

- Cadet
- Junior
- Senior
- Veteran
- *This is the word I'm looking for*

Example sentence: John is a ______ mechanic.

*The word does not require a military context, despite my above list having a military feel to it.*

Answer (score 2):

"a master" mechanic or "the consummate" mechanic would fit

Answer (score 0):

**primo,**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/primo)  perhaps an elaboration of prime.

> slang: exceptionally good of its kind; first-class, highly or most valuable.

As in:

> John is a **primo** mechanic.

and  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/primo)

> She completed her chief residency and surgical retina fellowship at
>   one her field’s **primo** facilities there. Washington Post Sep 9, 2018

Answer (score 0):

Generally used for artists, a good candidate is:

> **Virtuoso**.

I'm recommending this word because I feel that when people get really good at something, they do that thing as an art - as if playing with/in it.

---

Meaning:

- a person highly skilled in music or another artistic pursuit.

Example usage: a celebrated clarinet virtuoso | [as modifier]: virtuoso guitar playin.

---

<sub>I looked up the exact meaning in Apple's dictionary. Feel free to look it up anywhere else for more details.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The French 'sans pareil' (without a match, better than any other) also exists in English in the form of 'nonpareil' used after the noun, pronounced 'non per rail', more or less. It is a literary term says the Cambridge Dictionary Online. Their example sentence is

> He was a teacher nonpareil.

Your sentence, then

> He was a mechanic nonpareil.

Comment: That makes sense, the more common English term, which had completely slipped my mind until your answer, is *unparalleled.*